# Modify CHtml::activecheckBoxList to print checkboxes in columns

Tags: php, html, yii

i have checkbox list printed in one column, but i need it to print in columns and in every column should be for example 10 checkboxes.
My php code:

```
//$user_cats- array of categories. 
    echo CHtml::activecheckBoxList($categories,
           'selected['.$parent->id.']',
        CHtml::listData(
                $user_cats,
                'id',
                'title',
                ''
        ));
```

Maybe is there a way to modify CHtml::listData that it could print checkboxes in columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
CHtml::activecheckBoxList($categories,
       'selected['.$parent->id.']',
    CHtml::listData(
            $user_cats,
            'id',
            'title',                
    ), array('separator'=>'',
             'template'=>'<span class="checkbox-columns">{input} {label}</span>'),
    );
```

And then in my CSS something like:

```
span.checkbox-columns {
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Adjust the CSS, primarily the width percentage, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

First thing `CHtml::listData` generates a dataset that is suitable for use in `activeCheckboxList`, `dropdownlist` etc.

Now if you want to change how the check boxes appear on your page you need to pass the htmlOptions array to the `activeCheckBoxList`.
You can read more about it on [Yii activeCheckBoxList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeCheckBoxList-detail)

for example:

```
CHtml::activecheckBoxList($categories,
       'selected['.$parent->id.']',
    CHtml::listData(
            $user_cats,
            'id',
            'title',                
    ), array('separator'=>'--')
    );
```

So by default if you don't specify a separator it uses a line break but if your provide it it will use that separator instead.
Also if you want to add some more style or format the checkboxes a bit better you can do that as well. Just read the documentation, the link is included above. It is all possible through specifying additional options for the `htmlOptions` array.